# csv.html:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: [function] is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript

I have this error; can anyone help please?:

```
csv.html:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: download_csv is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>CSV for Discogs</title>
  <style>
  td {
    max-width: 15vw;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <input type="file" name="filename" id="fileInput">
    <div class="csv"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-/SIrNqv8h6QGKDuNoLGA4iret+kyesCkHGzVUUV0shc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="csv.js"></script>
    <button onclick="download_csv()">Download CSV</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS (relevant excerpt):

```
function download_csv() {
    var csv = 'Name,Title\n';
    data.forEach(function(row) {
            csv += row.join(',');
            csv += "\n";
    });
    console.log(csv);
    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'people.csv';
    hiddenElement.click();
}
```

I want the code to output a csv file when the button is pressed. I am using Atom to edit the code in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells us that `download_csv` is not a global in your script. This is one of the many reasons **not** to use `onclick`-attribute-style event handlers: The functions they call have to be globals.

Either:

1. Make it a global (not a great idea, the global namespace is already far too crowed), or
2. Use modern event handling, perhaps by giving your `button` an `id` and then using `document.getElementById("the-id").addEventListener("click", download_csv);` to hook it up.

Comment: OK, thanks. So should the HTML perhaps be...

    <button onclick="getElementById('download_csv')">Download CSV</button>

Comment: @double-happiness - No. The HTML would be `<button id="some-id">..` The other part goes in your script file, where JavaScript code belongs. (JS code in attributes is not best practice.)